# Wise to Wix conversion

Tags: build, wix, windows-installer, wise

Our organization is going to replace the installer technology from WISE to WIX.
I am able to create the WIX Source files using the decompiler(dark.exe).Able to make the installer working by doing a lot of trial and error.But still there are a lot of custom actions in Wise that should be considered while moving to WIX. Is there any easy way to find out the equalent WIX custom actions.

Comment: You should look first to standard MSI actions to accomplish something before custom actions; then to [WiX-provided custom actions](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/); then to your own.

Comment: Been there (converted installers from WISE to WIX). Unfortunately AFAIK there is no easy way to find the "equivalent" actions. I could be helpful if you list the actions you have difficulties with.